# Unable to Add component through innerHtml

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience

I'm unable to add my already created components through innerHtml having **id="myId"**.
Components are **c:Contact360_Contact_Info_L1** and **c:Contact360_Contact_Info_L2**.
Are we not allowed this lightning or is there any other way to display it?

**Component:**

```
<aura:component >
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
    <div id="myId"></div>
</aura:component>
```

**Controller:**

```
({
    doInit: function(component, event, helper) {
        var temp = ''+
            '<div class="slds-card__body">'+
                '<div class="slds-card__body_inner slds-grid slds-wrap">'+
                    '<c:Contact360_Contact_Info_L1 aura:id="Comp1" otherCompId="Comp2" thisCompId="Comp1"/>' +
                    '<c:Contact360_Contact_Info_L2 aura:id="Comp2" otherCompId="Comp1" thisCompId="Comp2"/>'+
                    '</div></div>';
        var element = document.getElementById("myId");
        element.innerHTML = temp;
    }
})
```

This innerHtml is working when I'm simply writing something instead of calling the components there.

Comment: No you can't assign that straight to innerHTML specially because you are injecting a component. You can create your component dynamically using $A.createComponent, https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_cb_dynamic_cmp_async.htm, but it will require a bit of rework in your code.

Answer (score 3):

In general Lightning Component markup is not parsed by the browser as HTML. It's parsed by the Lightning Framework, and then delivered to the browser in a JavaScript object-shaped format. But `innerHTML` is a property meant to be processed by the browser (actually Lightning Locker Service intercepts it, but still only raw HTML is handled). So what you have typed just literally injects the markup for the browser to see and it has no idea what to do with it.

In general you should not be constructing anything in Lightning via raw `innerHTML`. Any problem you are trying to solve that way can probably be solved in a more component-friendly manner.